# Admob not displaying ads

Tags: swift, admob

```
  @IBOutlet weak var MyBanner: GADBannerView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    //Request

    let request = GADRequest()
    request.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID]

    //Set up ad

    MyBanner.adUnitID = "omitted "
    MyBanner.rootViewController = self
    MyBanner.delegate = self

    MyBanner.load(request)
```

I've ensured that I'm using the correct adUnitID and that the IBOutlet is correctly assigned, however when I run the application only whitespace appears where the ad should be. 
Here is a screenshot of the output. [image: screenshot]

This is what the debugger outputs when running the code:

> 2018-11-07 22:12:42.806497-0600 CoverMe[7740:78040] Failed to set
>   (keyPath) user defined inspected property on (UITabBar): [ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key
>   value coding-compliant for the key keyPath. 2018-11-07
>   22:12:42.901273-0600 CoverMe[7740:78040] [MC] System group container
>   for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is
>   /Users/chomiak2/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/43BF3F97-0A4D-4BFA-9FF5-1E85CF8DD784/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
>   2018-11-07 22:12:42.901798-0600 CoverMe[7740:78040] [MC] Reading from
>   private effective user settings. 2018-11-07 22:12:42.913366-0600
>   CoverMe[7740:78081] Could not successfully update network info during
>   initialization. 2018-11-07 22:12:43.439099-0600 CoverMe[7740:78108]
>   WF: === Starting WebFilter logging for process CoverMe 2018-11-07
>   22:12:43.439570-0600 CoverMe[7740:78108] WF: _userSettingsForUser :
>   (null) 2018-11-07 22:12:43.439822-0600 CoverMe[7740:78108] WF:
>   _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried with Test Id? was it working for test Ad id?

- If you are using 17+ AdMob sdk (implementation
  'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.0.0') you need to
  specify app id in AndroidManifest.xml file. You can find your app id in Admob App settings

  ```
  <meta-data
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
      android:value="@string/app_id"/>
  ```
- Also try uninstalling the app manually and reinstall again without
  making any changes.
- Many times AdMob take 24-48 hrs to serve ads, so test after sometime otherwise use any old Ad Id

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it! Really stupid error, but you have to wait for your admob account to be approved before ads will show up.